# Applications of matroid theory.

Tags: applications, matroids

I am considering learning about matroid theory. I would like to know what the applications of matroid theory are (if they exist) beforehand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matroid theory finds applications in computer science, most notably in the study of [Greedy algorithms](http://math.fau.edu/locke/Greedy.htm).

Of course, as with any abstraction, matroid theory enhances one's understanding of linear dependence and independence.

Comment: any book you could recommend to me (I used Axler for linear algebra)

Comment: I'm not really an expert on matroids so I can't really recommend a book. I just read some things I found online to get the basic definitions and some of the main theorems and related problems.

Comment: A good classic book is "Combinatorial optimization" by Eugene Lawler. There's also another excellent book with the same title by Papadimitriou and Stiglitz. Edmonds is the authority on matroids, so pick up some of his papers from the 70s.

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo Assuming you're still interested, you may want to take a look at László Lovász's papers on [greedoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedoid).

Answer (score 2):

there are many applications from matroid structures and related topics in coding theory that leads to crypsoystem and making good definitions to working with them in related algebraic theorems..  for example relation betwean decomposible codes via matroid decomposition theprems and quasigroup methodes for explain M-codes...